# Sun ATLS2XGF 10gbe + Ubuntu 18.04 + PowerConnect 6224 with 10gbe xfp

Tags: 18.04

So I got 2 Sun ATLS2XGF dual 10gbe xfp NIC's for ~ 30USD. I figured they were just some rebrand like Sun raid controllers. Windows refuse's to find a driver, but that's no big deal. I got these for a ubuntu server. So I plop 1 in my server and everything seem good. A little complaining about a bad xfp, so i take one from the second card and wait for the fiber to arrive. It came in yesterday and I hooked everything up and I get links @ 10gb full duplex. So I added entries for the interfaces in my /etc/network/interfaces (i reverted from netplan to use OpenvSwitch) file like so:

```
auto enp133s0f0
iface enp133s0f0 inet dhcp

auto enp136s0f0
iface enp136s0f0 inet dhcp
```

No address after restarting the network, so i reboot just to make sure. I try a static address. I get an address,  but cant ping the switch.

lspci show's it as 4

Ethernet controller: Oracle/SUN Multithreaded 10-Gigabit Ethernet Network Controller (rev 01)

dmesd | grep niu (the driver)

```
[    1.322261] niu: niu.c:v1.1 (Apr 22, 2010)
[    1.322733] niu 0000:88:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): niu_get_invariants() VPD offset [00016e00]
[    1.322795] niu 0000:88:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: start[16e14] end[16f94]
[    1.323032] niu 0000:88:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [local-mac-address] len[6]
[    1.323222] niu 0000:88:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [version] len[41]
[    1.323800] niu 0000:88:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [model] len[15]
[    1.324148] niu 0000:88:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [board-model] len[12]
[    1.325375] niu 0000:88:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [num-mac-addresses] len[1]
[    1.325518] niu 0000:88:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [phy-type] len[4]
[    1.325567] niu 0000:88:00.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: FCODE major(3) minor(20)
[    1.325701] niu: niu0: Found PHY 00206033 type PMA/PMD at phy_port 8
[    1.325914] niu: niu0: Found PHY 00206033 type PCS at phy_port 8
[    1.326186] niu: niu0: Found PHY 00206033 type PMA/PMD at phy_port 9
[    1.329509] niu: niu0: Found PHY 00206033 type PCS at phy_port 9
[    1.336801] niu: niu0: Port 0 [8 RX chans] [12 TX chans]
[    1.336880] niu: niu0: Port 1 [8 RX chans] [12 TX chans]
[    1.336957] niu: niu0: Port 0 RDC tbl(0) [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ]
[    1.337039] niu: niu0: Port 0 RDC tbl(1) [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ]
[    1.337123] niu: niu0: Port 0 RDC tbl(2) [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ]
[    1.337208] niu: niu0: Port 0 RDC tbl(3) [ 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ]
[    1.337294] niu: niu0: Port 1 RDC tbl(4) [ 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ]
[    1.337405] niu: niu0: Port 1 RDC tbl(5) [ 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ]
[    1.337513] niu: niu0: Port 1 RDC tbl(6) [ 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ]
[    1.337621] niu: niu0: Port 1 RDC tbl(7) [ 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ]
[    2.609347] niu: Port 0 PMA_PMD(MII_STAT1000) [0001]
[    2.610314] niu: Port 0 USER_DEV3(0x20) [1005]
[    2.611207] niu: Port 0 PHYXS(MII_NWAYTEST) [0000]
[    2.879376] niu: eth1: NIU Ethernet 00:21:28:84:d5:10
[    2.879377] niu: eth1: Port type[XMAC] mode[10G:FIBER] XCVR[XPCS] phy[xgf]
[    2.879945] niu 0000:88:00.1 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): niu_get_invariants() VPD offset [00016e00]
[    2.880006] niu 0000:88:00.1 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: start[16e14] end[16f94]
[    2.880260] niu 0000:88:00.1 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [local-mac-address] len[6]
[    2.880450] niu 0000:88:00.1 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [version] len[41]
[    2.881029] niu 0000:88:00.1 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [model] len[15]
[    2.881373] niu 0000:88:00.1 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [board-model] len[12]
[    2.882599] niu 0000:88:00.1 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [num-mac-addresses] len[1]
[    2.882742] niu 0000:88:00.1 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [phy-type] len[4]
[    2.882791] niu 0000:88:00.1 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: FCODE major(3) minor(20)
[    4.089342] niu: Port 1 PMA_PMD(MII_STAT1000) [0001]
[    4.090035] niu: Port 1 USER_DEV3(0x20) [1005]
[    4.090569] niu: Port 1 PHYXS(MII_NWAYTEST) [0000]
[    4.168860] niu: eth0: NIU Ethernet 00:21:28:84:d5:11
[    4.169531] niu: eth0: Port type[XMAC] mode[10G:FIBER] XCVR[XPCS] phy[xgf]
[    4.170719] niu 0000:88:00.2 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): niu_get_invariants() VPD offset [00016e00]
[    4.170780] niu 0000:88:00.2 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: start[16e14] end[16f94]
[    4.171016] niu 0000:88:00.2 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [local-mac-address] len[6]
[    4.171206] niu 0000:88:00.2 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [version] len[41]
[    4.171784] niu 0000:88:00.2 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [model] len[15]
[    4.172131] niu 0000:88:00.2 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [board-model] len[12]
[    4.173359] niu 0000:88:00.2 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [num-mac-addresses] len[1]
[    4.173502] niu 0000:88:00.2 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [phy-type] len[4]
[    4.173551] niu 0000:88:00.2 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: FCODE major(3) minor(20)
[    4.173555] niu 0000:88:00.2 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): niu_put_parent() port[2]
[    4.174120] niu 0000:88:00.3 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): niu_get_invariants() VPD offset [00016e00]
[    4.174180] niu 0000:88:00.3 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: start[16e14] end[16f94]
[    4.174417] niu 0000:88:00.3 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [local-mac-address] len[6]
[    4.174606] niu 0000:88:00.3 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [version] len[41]
[    4.175184] niu 0000:88:00.3 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [model] len[15]
[    4.175527] niu 0000:88:00.3 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [board-model] len[12]
[    4.176759] niu 0000:88:00.3 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [num-mac-addresses] len[1]
[    4.176901] niu 0000:88:00.3 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: Reading in property [phy-type] len[4]
[    4.176950] niu 0000:88:00.3 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): VPD_SCAN: FCODE major(3) minor(20)
[    4.176953] niu 0000:88:00.3 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): niu_put_parent() port[3]
[    4.179410] niu 0000:88:00.0 enp136s0f0: renamed from eth1
[    4.200598] niu 0000:88:00.1 enp136s0f1: renamed from eth0
[  315.293446] niu 0000:88:00.0 enp136s0f0: Link is up at 10Gb/sec, full duplex
[  495.068363] niu 0000:88:00.0 enp136s0f0: Link is up at 10Gb/sec, full duplex
[  609.461609] niu: Port 0 PMA_PMD(MII_STAT1000) [0001]
[  609.461678] niu: Port 0 USER_DEV3(0x20) [1005]
[  609.461746] niu: Port 0 PHYXS(MII_NWAYTEST) [0000]
[  737.134734] niu: Port 0 PMA_PMD(MII_STAT1000) [0001]
[  737.134802] niu: Port 0 USER_DEV3(0x20) [1005]
[  737.134868] niu: Port 0 PHYXS(MII_NWAYTEST) [0000]
[  748.274763] niu: Port 1 PMA_PMD(MII_STAT1000) [0001]
[  748.274831] niu: Port 1 USER_DEV3(0x20) [1005]
[  748.274897] niu: Port 1 PHYXS(MII_NWAYTEST) [0000]
```

sorry, but i couldnt figure out the formatting to make it legible. something about copy/paste from putty loses the returns.

The PowerConnect show's a 10gb link and the port is set to access. The only other settings ive changed from factory default is 2 lacp lag's where the server connects currently, and the login. It's the most recent firmware as of last last month.

Are the Sun cards not just a rebrand but a custom with only SUN and RHEL drivers? Am I missing something simple? Any thoughts?

This is my first time setting up a fiber interface, so I could be missing something simple.

Comment: a new uplink module and XFP's fix it. I think it was the Cisco SFP+ that came in my switch. I think they might only be for up link to cisco switches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new uplink module and XFP's fix it. I think it was the Cisco SFP+ that came in my switch. I think they might only be for up link to cisco switches.

All my fault, Ubuntu got an ip as soon as i booted with the new uplink module in the PowerConnect 6224. 2 evenings waisted thinking it was a driver issue. The driver from sun for redhat is called nxge, according to the Sun doc. In ubuntu its apparently niu.

@chili555, thanks for the formatting. Is there a guide/wiki to posting here? I know nothing about HTML or any programing other than a very basic shell script.

Comment: I am unaware of any guide. I simply hover over the little symbols above the box where you compose or edit the question and select the formatting I believe is appropriate. In this case, I used {} for 'code sample.' You can see the result instantly in the preview below the compose box. If it isn't what I want, I simply change it to another. Wow! I guess I just wrote the guide! I'm glad your issue is sorted.